# Azure AD B2C: Can I intercept the login flow and either approve/deny the token?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm struggling to figure out a way to hook into the authentication/authorization/token issuance process.

I want to be able to authenticate users, as well as prevent users that are banned from logging in.

I want things to work this way:

- Upon providing their username + password, users get logged in if the credentials are valid
- If the credentials are valid, we do an additional check as to whether the users are banned or not (by checking their username in a custom database)
- If the user is banned, deny login

I want to know whether Azure AD or Azure AD B2C supports this ability to hook into its processes, and if so, where can I find more about it? documentation? sample code? etc...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily attainable by using the `Identity Trust Framework`, also known as `Custom Policies`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-trust-frameworks

You can then use a REST API `Technical Profile` and use conditions within your `User Journey` that will allow your flow to occur as you have indicated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile

I would also encourage you to review these samples from the Community Github Repo:

- Demonstrates using an AAD B2C Extension Property to store an attribute that is then conditionally handled. - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon
- Demonstrates how you can use a REST API call during your User Journeys. https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/rest-api-idp

It is worth noting that there are some features coming for API Connectors within the more simplistic `User Flows,` but I am unable to speak on those.